# PHP function ord() returns wrong code of cirilyc charecter

Tags: php, character-encoding, cyrillic, ord

The utf-8 charcode of Russian 'A' is 1040 (decimal). Javascript do it right:

```
> 'А'.charCodeAt(0)
> 1040
```

But PHP code

```
<?php echo ord('А');?>
```

returns 208.

Please note that in the beginning of the PHP code I have:

```
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 'ru_RU' );
```

How can I implement coding and decoding of UTF-8 characters in PHP? Use another function instead of `ord`?

Comment: Your file saved as UTF-8?

Comment: chr(1040) == **DLE** and not an "А"

Comment: @AdrianPreuss, yes - all files are saved in UTF-8 w/o BOM. This link says that Rus. А has code 0x0410 (=1040 decimal): http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024&number=1024

Comment: See references, 208 is correct: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024&utf8=dec

Comment: @AdrianPreuss there specified '208 144' not 208 (cirilyc chars are two byted in UTF-8)

Comment: than split it, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $the_char   = 'А';
        $byte_1     = $the_char[0];
        $byte_2     = $the_char[1];
        print (ord($byte_1) - 192) * 64 + (ord($byte_2) - 128);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: calculation is for all 2byte UTF-8 Chars

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. Unlike Javascript PHP considering the charecters of a string as a byte sequence. Javascript considering the char as a separate char for 1-byte, 2-byte (etc.) characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function ord_utf8($s){
return (int) ($s=unpack('C*',$s[0].$s[1].$s[2].$s[3]))&&$s[1]<(1<<7)?$s[1]:
($s[1]>239&&$s[2]>127&&$s[3]>127&&$s[4]>127?(7&$s[1])<<18|(63&$s[2])<<12|(63&$s[3])<<6|63&$s[4]:
($s[1]>223&&$s[2]>127&&$s[3]>127?(15&$s[1])<<12|(63&$s[2])<<6|63&$s[3]:
($s[1]>193&&$s[2]>127?(31&$s[1])<<6|63&$s[2]:0)));
}

print_r(ord_utf8('А'));

// Output 1040
```

You can found more explanations about it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42600959/7558876