# How to pass the UTF-8 encoded strings between JS and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, utf-8, character-encoding

**Preamble:**

I found out that [Javascript and PHP has different approach to UTF-8 multibyte character codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575085/php-function-ord-returns-wrong-code-of-cirilyc-charecter):
- PHP treats multibyte char as several separated bytes; JS treats multibyte char as a single integer (larger than 255)
- PHP keeps all auxiliary bits in the codes; JS strips all those bits.

So code of Russian letter 'А' will be

- 208 and 144 in PHP

  1040 in JS

**Problem description**

I need to expose a string to some encoding routine in JS in a client's browser and than decode one in PHP on a server side. To encode and decode the strings I used the JS string property `charCodeAt` and PHP function `chr()`. As I mentioned above this approach is not working as the codes are different in PHP and JS.

**Question**

Is there any function in PHP to strip auxiliary bits from UTF-8 byte sequence **OR** is there any function in Javascript to add those auxiliary bits to char codes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function ord() returns wrong code of cirilyc charecter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575085/php-function-ord-returns-wrong-code-of-cirilyc-charecter)

Comment: @AdrianPreuss it is not duplicate! It is an extension of my previous question. Please read a bit deeper to my new question.

Answer (score 0):

use **mb_*** functions otherwise split the bytes. Each byte with `ord`

```
<?php
    $the_char   = 'А';
    $byte_1     = $the_char[0];
    $byte_2     = $the_char[1];
    print (ord($byte_1) - 192) * 64 + (ord($byte_2) - 128);
?>
```

The same you can make with Javascript

Comment: I see that you are literally casting those UTF-8 auxiliary bits manually. So there is no better way like library or intrinsic function?

Comment: Yeah, i've found a little Git-Project. I think that can wake up your interests: https://github.com/fluxbb/utf8/blob/master/functions/ord.php  but its make the same as my snippet