# ord() doesn't work with utf-8

Tags: php, unicode, ascii

according to ISO 8859-1

€ Symbol has decimal value 128

My default php script encoding is

```
echo mb_internal_encoding(); //ISO-8859-1
```

So now as PHP

```
echo chr(128);  //Output exactly what i want '€'
```

But

```
echo ord('€');  //opposite it returns 226, it should be 128
```

why it is so?

Comment: Did you read the manual? It's kinda explained in there... [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

Comment: yes i have read that first ord() function complements chr().

Comment: Have you also read the comments on the page @Naruto has linked to? Especially the second one? It explains in detail why `ord()` doesn't work with utf-8: `For single-byte encodings such as (7-bit) ASCII and the ISO 8859 family, this will correspond to the first character, and will be the position of that character in the encoding's mapping table. For multi-byte encodings, such as UTF-8 or UTF-16, the byte may not represent a complete character`

Comment: my default encoding is 
**echo mb_internal_encoding(); //ISO-8859-1**

Comment: But chr() also support single-byte encodings. why it output '€ ' for 128 decimal value

Comment: 2018! see new [**mb_ord()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php), for **PHP v7.2.0+**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)#Comparison_table) and [FileFormat](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20aC/index.htm),

- ISO-8859-1 doesn't have the Euro symbol at all
- ISO-8859-15 has it at codepoint 164 (`0xA4`)
- Windows-1252 has it at codepoint 128 (`0x80`)
- Unicode has the Euro symbol at codepoint 8364 (`0x20AC`)
- UTF-8 encodes that as `0xE2 0x82 0xAC`. The first byte `E2` is 226 in decimal.

So it seems your source file is encoded in UTF-8 (and `ord()` only returns the first byte), whereas your output is in Windows-1252.

Comment: my source file default encoding is `echo mb_internal_encoding(); //ISO-8859-1`

Comment: @Curious The return value of that function says absolutely nothing about **what encoding your source code file is saved as.**

Comment: @Curious: No it isn't. 8859-1 doesn't even have a Euro symbol. Read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-internal-encoding.php)

Answer (score 5):

It is only for 2018's **PHP v7.2.0+**.

### mb_ord()

Now you can use [mb_ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php).
Example `echo mb_ord('€','UTF-8');`

See also [mb_chr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php), to get the UTF-8 representation of a decimal code. 
Example `echo mb_chr(2048,'UTF-8');`.

---

The *best practice* is to be universal, save **all your PHP scripts as UTF-8** (see @deceze).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> echo ord('€');  //opposite it returns 226, it should be 128
> ```

Your .php file is saved as UTF-8 (you saved it as UTF-8 in your text editor when you saved the file to disk). The string literal in there contains the bytes `E2 82 AC`; visualised it's something like this:

```
echo ord('\xE2\x82\xAC');
```

Open the file in a hex editor for real clarity.

`ord` only returns a single integer in the range of 0 - 255. Your string literal contains *three* bytes, for which `ord` would need to return three integers, which it won't. It returns only the first one, which is `226`.

Save the file in different encodings in your text editor and you'll see different results.

Answer (score 1):

This PHP function return the decimal number of the first character in string.

- If the number is lower than **128** then the character is encoded in 1 octet.
- Elseif the number is lower than **2048** then the character is encoded in 2 octets.
- Elseif the number is lower than **65536** then the character is encoded in 3 octets.
- Elseif the number is lower than **1114112** then the character is encoded in 4 octets.

```
function ord_utf8($s){
return (int) ($s=unpack('C*',$s[0].$s[1].$s[2].$s[3]))&&$s[1]<(1<<7)?$s[1]:
($s[1]>239&&$s[2]>127&&$s[3]>127&&$s[4]>127?(7&$s[1])<<18|(63&$s[2])<<12|(63&$s[3])<<6|63&$s[4]:
($s[1]>223&&$s[2]>127&&$s[3]>127?(15&$s[1])<<12|(63&$s[2])<<6|63&$s[3]:
($s[1]>193&&$s[2]>127?(31&$s[1])<<6|63&$s[2]:0)));
}

echo ord_utf8('€');

// Output 8364 then this character is encoded in 3 octets
```

You can check the result in https://eval.in/748181 …

The **ord_utf8** function is the reciprocal of **chr_utf8** (print one utf8 character from decimal number)

```
function chr_utf8($n,$f='C*'){
return $n<(1<<7)?chr($n):($n<1<<11?pack($f,192|$n>>6,1<<7|191&$n):
($n<(1<<16)?pack($f,224|$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):
($n<(1<<20|1<<16)?pack($f,240|$n>>18,1<<7|63&$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):'')));
}

for($test=1;$test<1114111;$test++)
if (ord_utf8(chr_utf8($test))!==$test)
die('Error found');

echo 'No error';

// Output No error
```