# PHP Turkish Characters to ASCII Giving Same Output

Tags: php, ascii

ord('Ö') is giving 195 and also ord('Ç') is giving 195 too. I didn't get what is the error. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575721/ord-doesnt-work-with-utf-8) thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ord() doesn't work with utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575721/ord-doesnt-work-with-utf-8)

Comment: Use `mb_ord('Ç','UTF-8');`  instead of `ord();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ord — Convert the first byte of a string to a value between 0 and 255

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

The question is - what the charset of the source file?
Since 'Ö' and 'Ç' both are not ASCII symbols, they are represented as two bytes in UTF-8 encoding

Ö - 0xC3 0x96

Ç - 0xC3 0x87

As you can see, both characters has first bytes 0xC3 (=195 dec.)

So, you need to decide what code you want to get?

For example, you can convert the UTF-8 string into Windows-1254:

```
print ord(iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1254', 'Ö')); // 214
print ord(iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1254', 'Ç')); // 199
```

Or you may want to get unicode [Code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). To do that you can first convert the string into UTF-32, and then decode a 32-bit number:

```
function get_codepoint($utf8char) {
    $bin = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-32BE', $utf8char); // convert to UTF-32 big endian
    $a = unpack('Ncp', $bin); // unpack binary data
    return $a['cp']; // get the code point
}
print get_codepoint('Ö'); // 214
print get_codepoint('Ç'); // 199
```

Or in php 7.2 and later you can simple use [mb_ord](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord)

```
print mb_ord('Ö'); // 214
print mb_ord('Ç'); // 199
```